# Parse large RDF in Python

Tags: python, xml, sax, rdf

I'd like to parse a very large (about 200MB) RDF file in python. Should I be using sax or some other library? I'd appreciate some very basic code that I can build on, say to retrieve a tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A video on how to use SAX from Stanford is available here http://timmcnamara.co.nz/post/386007776/learning-about-xml-in-python-this-was-a-great

Comment: @user201140 what do you mean with 'retrieve a tag' ? Normally when parsing RDF you should be looking for the triples in it. Could yo explain a bit more your use case of RDF ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are looking for fast performance then I'd recommend you to use [Raptor](http://librdf.org/raptor/) with the [Redland Python Bindings](http://librdf.org/bindings/). The performance of Raptor, written in C, is way better than RDFLib. And you can use the python bindings in case you don't want to deal with C.

Another advice for improving performance, forget about parsing RDF/XML, go with other flavor of RDF like Turtle or [NTriples](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/). Specially parsing ntriples is much faster than parsing RDF/XML. This is because the ntriples syntax is simpler.

You can transform your RDF/XML into ntriples using rapper, a tool that comes with raptor:

```
rapper -i rdfxml -o ntriples YOUR_FILE.rdf > YOUR_FILE.ntriples
```

The ntriples file will contain triples like:

```
<s1> <p> <o> .
<s2> <p2> "literal" .
```

and parsers tend to be very efficient handling this structure. Moreover, memory wise is more efficient than RDF/XML because, as you can see, this data structure is smaller.

The code below is a simple example using the redland python bindings:

```
import RDF
parser=RDF.Parser(name="ntriples") #as name for parser you can use ntriples, turtle, rdfxml, ...
model=RDF.Model()
stream=parser.parse_into_model(model,"file://file_path","http://your_base_uri.org")
for triple in model:
    print triple.subject, triple.predicate, triple.object
```

The base URI is the prefixed URI in case you use relative URIs inside your RDF document. You can check documentation about the Python Redland bindings API in [here](http://librdf.org/docs/pydoc/RDF.html)

If you don't care much about performance then use [RDFLib](http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/), it is simple and easy to use.

Comment: so much that is not worth measuring it.

Comment: I did some benchmarking to compare rdflib and Redland RDF and Redland is indeed faster, although it seems to be more error-prone: **5mb** file RDF = 1.4 seconds, rdflib = 12.8 seconds. **50mb** file RDF = 9.4 seconds, rdflib = 1 minute, 7 seconds. **535 mb** file RDF = could't get it to work, rdflib = 12 minutes, 3 seconds. Also, for those looking for another example on how to use the library, see the [examples.py](https://github.com/dajobe/redland-bindings/blob/master/python/example.py) file in the repo

Answer (score 12):

I second the suggestion that you try out rdflib. It's nice and quick prototyping, and the BerkeleyDB backend store scales pretty well into the millions of triples if you don't want to load the whole graph into memory.

```
import rdflib

graph = rdflib.Graph("Sleepycat")
graph.open("store", create=True)
graph.parse("big.rdf")

# print out all the triples in the graph
for subject, predicate, object in graph:
    print subject, predicate, object
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, SAX is great for performance but it's a pain to write. Unless I am having issues, I tend to avoid programming with it.

"Very large" is dependent on the RAM of the machine. Assuming that your computer has over 1GB memory, [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), [`pyxml`](http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/) or some other library e will be fine for 200mb files.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if sax is the best solution, but IBM seems to think it works for high-performance XML parsing with Python: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/. Their example RDF dwarfs yours in size (200MB vs. 1.9GB), so their solution should work for you.

This article's examples start pretty basic and pick up quickly.

Answer (score 1):

For RDF processing in Python, consider using an RDF library such as RDFLib. If you also need a triplestore, more heavyweight solutions are available as well, but may not be needed here ([PySesame](http://pysesame.projects.semwebcentral.org/), [neo4jrdf](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-rdf/) with [neo4jpy](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j.py/)).

Before writing your own SAX parser for RDF, check out [rdfxml.py](http://infomesh.net/2003/rdfparser/):

```
import rdfxml
data = open('data.rdf', 'r').read()
rdfxml.parseRDF(data)
```

Comment: How do I import rdfxml? it says rename reference

Answer (score 1):

A very fast library to parse RDF files is [LightRdf](https://pypi.org/project/lightrdf/). It could be installed via pip. Code examples can be found on the project page.

If you want to parse triples from a gzipped RDF file, you can do this like that:

```
import lightrdf
import gzip

RDF_FILENAME = 'data.rdf.gz'

f = gzip.open(RDF_FILENAME, 'rb')
doc = lightrdf.RDFDocument(f, parser=lightrdf.xml.PatternParser)
for (s, p, o) in doc.search_triples(None, None, None)):
            print(s, p, o)
```