# Parsing large NTriples File Python

Tags: python, rdf, n-triples, redland

I am trying to parse a rather large NTriples file using the code from [Parse large RDF in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868888/parse-large-rdf-in-python)

I installed raptor and the redland-bindings for python.

```
import RDF
parser=RDF.Parser(name="ntriples") #as name for parser you can use ntriples, turtle, rdfxml, ...
model=RDF.Model()
stream=parser.parse_into_model(model,"file:./mybigfile.nt")
for triple in model:
    print triple.subject, triple.predicate, triple.object
```

However the program hangs and I suspect it is trying to load the entire file into memory or something because it does not start right away.

Anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slow because you are reading into an in-memory store (RDF.Model() default) which has no indexing.  So it gets slower and slower.  The parsing of N-Triples does stream from the file, it never sucks it all into memory.

See the [Redland storage modules documentation](http://librdf.org/docs/api/redland-storage-modules.html) for an overview of the storage models.  Here you probably want storage `type` 'hashes' and `hash-type` memory.

```
s = RDF.HashStorage("abc", options="hash-type='memory'")
model = RDF.Model(s)
```

(not tested)

Comment: Huh, I attempted using this but I still can't seem to read a ~2GB file.

Comment: parse_as_stream will work.  I just noticed your code does stream=...parse_into_model and then doesn't use stream.